# Unable to ping 2 laptops in same network (wireless)

Tags: windows, networking

I have 2 laptop. 1. Windows 7 2. Windows server 2008

I have my adsl wireless router and have disabled firewall on both machine. Also, I don't have any antivirus install on both machine. I could use internet in both laptops but however I can't ping one laptop with another. A few days ago it was working but not it is not. I am feeling v.helpless. Please ! help me sort this problem

Comment: IP address changed with DHCP renewal?

Comment: I have 1 computer with ip address automatically generated as 192.168.1.102 and other I set it as 192.168.1.101.
Howerver, in both machine i can run internet. How DHCP effects in it...?

Comment: If the address of one was being changed through DHCP - it does not always give you the same address. But it sounds like you have ruled this one. Can you ping from one to the other at all e.g. A to B works but not B to A or does it not work either way?

Comment: Make sure "client isolation" (sometimes call "AP isolation") is disabled in the wireless router.

Comment: Are they members of a domain or workgroup?

Comment: They are member of a workgroup. I coudln't find anything like client isolation. Also, I can't ping from A to B as well as B to A...

Comment: @user1370468: What's the make and model of the router?